# how can i copy text from the copy menu from a text control?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, mfc, controls

I get static text control on a dialog, and there is a copy menu when right-click. 
when I copy the selected text, nothing can be pasted. Someone said static text control has no copy function, I replace static text control with a edit control, which has copy default, but still copy nothing to paste. What's the problem for that?

There is the edit control below.

[image]

```
IDD_WZD_ADD_EVENTS DIALOGEX 0, 0, 342, 189
STYLE DS_SETFONT | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg 2", 0, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    LTEXT           "&Add events to the list in order of their appearance.",IDC_STATIC,21,1,165,8
    LTEXT           "How do I add events from Event Viewer?",IDC_EVENT_VIEWER_LINK_HELP,189,1,132,8
    LTEXT           "&Events: ",IDC_STATIC,21,12,163,8
    CONTROL         "List1",IDC_LST_EVENTS,"SysListView32",LVS_REPORT | LVS_SHOWSELALWAYS | LVS_NOSORTHEADER | WS_BORDER | WS_TABSTOP,21,21,278,62
    PUSHBUTTON      "",IDC_BTN_UP_EVENT,304,21,17,16,BS_ICON
    PUSHBUTTON      "",IDC_BTN_DOWN_EVENT,304,41,17,16,BS_ICON
    PUSHBUTTON      "A&dd",IDC_BTN_ADD_EVENT,21,87,50,14
    PUSHBUTTON      "Re&move",IDC_BTN_REMOVE_EVENT,75,87,49,14
    PUSHBUTTON      "Edi&t...",IDC_BTN_EDIT_EVENT,128,87,50,14
    CONTROL         "Any &order",IDC_CHK_ANY_ORDER,"Button",BS_AUTOCHECKBOX | WS_TABSTOP,226,90,73,10
    LTEXT           "&Rule description:",IDC_STATIC,21,106,300,8
    EDITTEXT        IDC_STEP_DESCRIPTION,21,114,300,74,ES_AUTOHSCROLL
END
```

Comment: Could not reproduce. What I did: 1. Opened Notepad, typed some text, copied that text with Edit-Copy. 2. Opened your dialog: right clicked on the edit control next to "Rue description", chose "Paste". The text was pasted correctly. Maybe you should tell us the exact sequence of operations you perform in order to reproduce the problem. Tell us what you expect and what you get.

Comment: Why don't you set your EDITTEXT as read-only?

Comment: @sergiol I have tried read-only for edit control. It doesn't work.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Hi, Michael, What I want to do is :1. select text, right-click,, choose the copy menu to copy test on the static test control in my dialog. 2. then I can paste the copied text on Notepad.

Comment: @MichaelWalz There is a rule wizard. I make such thing for creating and managing the rule I want. There are two ways opening my dialog: creating rule and edit rule. Those two ways open the same dialog and controls. However, I can copy text on the static text control on the way of creating rules while can't copy on the way of opening again for editing rules.

Comment: I add a picture just now —>https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWYXY.png. But I can't see the picture unless click "enter image description here"

Comment: The edit control below _"Rule decription:"_ is apparently read only, so it is normal you can't paste text. Are you sure you don't call [`SetReadOnly`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/b1533c30-7f10-4663-88d3-8b7f2c9f7024.aspx#cedit__setreadonly) on thbis edit control ?

Comment: I have called SetReadOnly on this edit control. Not help. Thanks Mechael. Maybe the problem is not related to the control's properties.